# Delete binary core data using a func

Tags: swift, image, core-data, delegates, binary-data

I want to delete a specific item in a core data binary data set. I have added all of my code below. I tried to follow what I was doing to save the data which worked but trying to apply it to deleting is not currently working. Do not know how to proceed to solve this. I am getting a runtime error at context delete at the helper class.

BASE CLASS

```
func deleteImage(imageNo:Int) {
   // first check the array bounds
   let info = DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.fetchImage()
   if info.count > imageNo {
       // check if the data is available
       if let imageData = info[imageNo].img {
           DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.deleteImage(data: imageData)
           
       } else {
           // no data
           print("data is empty")
       }
   } else {
       // image number is greater than array bounds
       print("you are asking out of bounds")
   }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  deleteImage(imageNo: 2)}
```

HELPER CLASS

```
class DataBaseHelper {

static let shareInstance = DataBaseHelper()
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext



func deleteImage(data: Data) {
    let imageInstance = Info(context: context)
    imageInstance.img = data
        
    do {
        try context.delete(data)
        print("Image is saved")
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA7Ea.png)

Comment: You can't just create a new Info class with the data you want to delete. You are getting an error because the Info instance has not yet been saved to the persistence layer. What you need to do is query for the Info object you want to delete, in other words, the instance that's already been saved, then delete that.

Comment: @RobC can you show me in code?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong above is

```
func deleteImage(data: Data) { 
    // here you create a new object with context 
    let imageInstance = Info(context: context) 

    // assigning data to object img property 
    imageInstance.img = data
   
    // deleting the unsaved object which cause error 
    do {
        try context.delete(data)
        print("Image is saved")
    } catch {
    // this part will be execute because object is not saved
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

So the thing is clear first you should have saved object to delete it otherwise it cause error.

So how to delete a specific object

```
class DataBaseHelper {

   static let shareInstance = DataBaseHelper()
   let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


  // pass the object in parameter it will delete the specific info object from CoreData that you will provide in argument
   func deleteInfo(info: Info) {
      do {
          try context.delete(info)
          print("Image is saved")
      } catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
   }

   // if you want to remove image but not the info row/object just assign it nil and save again 
   func deleteImage(info: Info) {
      info.img = nil
      do {
          try context.save()
          print("Image is removed but info still here")
      } catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
   }
}
```

this how you delete image

```
     if let info = info[imageNo]{
           DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.deleteImage(info: info)
           
       }
```

Comment: I am getting a error at    DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.deleteImage(data: imageData) in my base class after I implemented your code.

Comment: how would I delete image 2?

Comment: replace the last line with above edited lines

Comment: what function do I put it in. I tried swapping it with my error line and it does work. it produces more error.

Comment: what error you get kindly post it

Comment: I added a photo above with the error in it.

Comment: if you added my function to your helper class then use this Line

Comment: if let info = info[imageNo] {
          DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.deleteImage(info: info)
       }

Comment: What class do I put it in the base class or the helper class and in what func.

Comment: I replaced the line code with your code and I still got this error message nitializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Info'

Comment: the error is because of its not optional value just remove if let  and make it simple let  info = info[imageNo]